# Define order of execution of query parameters in Solr

Tags: solr, execution, query-string

Is there a way by which i can define the sequence of execution of query parameters in Solr?

e.g. First bq should executed and then fq

Comment: Why would this matter? The `fq` will limit the set of returned documents as an intersection with the query and other `fq` parameters. The boost query will be applied to all documents regardless - a filter doesn't know anything about (or can affect) the score of a document.

Comment: We have usecase where we use 
fq NOT (To exclude)
bq (to boost/Pin)
fq (to filter)

But want the boosted/pinned documents should come into the response even after fq (filter)

Comment: So you want to keep certain documents after your filter? In that case you have to modify your filter instead; filters are sets that are intersected with the existing result set, so they only remove documents. Your filter needs to be modified to not include those documents that you are boosting, for example by including the boost query as an additional match. Add examples to your question for a more detailed response.

Comment: To clarify: your filter needs to be modified so it doesn't exclude the documents you want to keep (i.e. those you're applying the boost to). The sequence of filters should not matter, as they describe sets of documents where the intersection between all filters are the documents that are being returned.